# Length of api key in wso2 APIM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, api-key

I wanted to know a few things related to api key.

As I have checked, the format for api key in wso2 is base64(header).base64(payload).base64(signature).

What is the maximum length of an api key in wso2?

Does the length of api key fluctuates application to application or fixed for all applications?

Answer (score 0):

If it's JWT the length will fluctuate based on the content. So for every application at least the application section in the payload
would change, so each application will have a different JWT token.

```json
"application": {
    "owner": "admin",
    "tierQuotaType": null,
    "tier": "10PerMin",
    "name": "Test",
    "id": 2,
    "uuid": "728fac14-1653-44d3-8542-15ce758d8fe5"
  }
```